# Golang How to return all history in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to return all history from MongoDB, and I have it returning good in my CLI but not in Postman or localhost:8080/path/to/history. It returns just the last record instead of the entire history.

```
func (h History) GetAll(ctx context.Context) (interface{}, error) {
    cursor, err := collection().Find(ctx, bson.D{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var results bson.D
    var resultsSlice []bson.D
    //if err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &results); err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal(err)
    //} //this returns all history but empty values

    defer cursor.Close(ctx)
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        if err = cursor.Decode(&results); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            if err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &results); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                resultsSlice = append(resultsSlice, results)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(results)
    }
    //fmt.Println(results)
    return results, nil
```

Comment: Your loop will read all documents, so there will be nothing left for the following `cursor.All()` call. Remove the loop, a single `cursor.All()` call will read all documents into `results`.

Comment: And you have to return the `results` value, not the `cursor`, a `cursor` does not contain the documents, it's to interact with the database!